# Excluding users from XDB Data

Tags: xdb

We have certain users on our site that are used only for testing. We want to excluded these users from our XDB data so that they don't show up in AB Testing,  path analyser, etc.

Has anyone been able to do this? I was think about tagging the user but then I am not sure where to configure XDB to ignore these tagged users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the user that you want to exclude, do this in a page request:

```
Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.NeverSave;
```

This will make sure that neither the interaction nor the contact are saved to the Collection database.

Answer (score 4):

If test users credentials are used within your team and you know their ip address. You can exclude those ip addresses in Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config file. It will not require a code change and can be handled in configurations.